# Staging To Publishing - One table or two?

Tags: mysql

I have a system that scrapes data and feeds it into a database. I then edit and modify that data using a web interface, before finally publishing it out.

Effectively this forms a 'staging' area and a 'publishing' area. Is it best to have these as two separate tables, or utilise a 'status' column that shows whether the data is in the 'staging' state or 'published'?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the scope and size of your database, this might be a saclability problem: I assume the user count for editing is much smaller, than the user count for viewing published information.

If these assumptions hold and you might ever need to scale, you are better off separating the staging from the publishing area, as they might once be on totally different systems.